# Are end-to-end tests better than unit tests, in situations where both are applicable?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, end-to-end

Let me first define what I mean by unit and end-to-end tests. Let's say you have a program with a bunch of Java classes: A invokes B, which invokes C, and so on.

A unit test is a test for A mocking out B, and separately a test for B mocking out C, and so on.

An end-to-end test is a test for A that tests A and, transitively, B and C.

For simplicity, and to keep the discussion focused on the topic at hand rather than getting distracted by secondary details, let's assume that the system as a whole is stateless: you invoke the top-level (A) with an input, and you get an output. A given input has exactly one valid output.

To be clear, I am not including external systems here, like RPCs to other servers, databases, external state like the filesystem, UIs of any kind ("assert that programmatically tapping the Delete button deletes the current document"), etc. We're just talking about a bunch of classes within the same process.

Now, there are two approaches one can take:

1. Write end-to-end tests that try to cover all possible inputs and states. Write unit tests only when needed, like if a particular class is not adequately tested by the end-to-end test, or if the end-to-end test fails and you find it helpful to write a unit test to localise the bug. But in general, the goal is to have thorough end-to-end tests.
2. Write unit tests that test each class or component exhaustively. Write an end-to-end test as an afterthought, or perhaps not at all. Even if you write it, don't try to exhaustively test all possible inputs.

I prefer (1), because if the end-to-end tests pass, and are exhaustive, I *know* that the system as a whole works for all the cases I tested. Whereas if each class or component works correctly, there could still be bugs at the points of integration between them, which is where I read most bugs occur (sorry, I don't have a reference right now).

So, which of these has worked better for you — having thorough end-to-end tests, or having thorough unit tests? Why? Please give concrete reasons so that I, and other readers, can evaluate the answers for themselves.

If this question is a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com, please move it there (moderators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider future changes and complexity to decide which one to go:

- If A's behaviour is likely fixed (says it's an API), while B & C are likely to be replaced/changed in the near future (says they are internal components that use an external library that is near its new release date), then I would go with end-to-end testing of A.
- If end-to-end testing of A will result in a very exhaustive list of test cases, or if there are too many test cases that are too hard to construct, I would go with unit testing of A, B and C.

I often find myself using a mix of both end-to-end and unit tests. End-to-end tests cover the crucial cases (which amount to about 60-70% coverage of all participating classes), while unit tests cover the rest (exceptions, very rare/deep execution paths), or I add in whenever I want to be more confident in my logic.

Answer (score 5):

While it's impossible to provide a general answer to such a question, as a rule of thumb, you should be considering the [Test Pyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html):

- A few System Tests
- Some Integration Tests
- Lots of Unit Tests

The reason for that is [outlined by J.B. Rainsberger](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam), but the gist of it is that for any reasonably complex application, the **combinatorial explosion** of covering all possible behaviour prevents effective coverage by anything but unit tests. You'd have to write tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of integration tests to know if your system works or if it doesn't.

Comment: I covered the combinatorial explosion part by saying, "Write unit tests only when needed, like if a particular class is not adequately tested by the end-to-end test". With that qualification, would you agree with option 1 in my question?

Comment: @KartickVaddadi That really depends on what you mean by *adequately*. As [Steve Freeman explains, you may care about fail-safe systems, or 'safe fail' systems](http://www.higherorderlogic.com/2011/04/tdd-embracing-failure). If you're doing the latter, you may not need a lot of *coverage*, in which case integration tests may be all you need. However, it's quite clear from J.B. Rainsberger's exposition that for any non-trivial application, you'll need unit tests in order to achieve any reasonable degree of coverage.

Comment: By adequately, I mean testing all functionality that I'd like to test. Regarding your point that I'll need unit tests to achieve good coverage, sure, option 1 does not say "don't write unit tests". It just says "Before writing a unit test, try to write an end-to-end test. If you can, great. If not, write a unit test." So, at the end of it, we'll have good coverage.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no right answer (which is why I’ve voted to close as primarily opinion based).  The best approach is largely going to be situational and to some extent by how you chose to define a unit.  From your description of the problem domain, you have class A, calls class B, calls class C.  You are treating all classes as units.  This is one approach, but [it’s not the only approach](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/).  You could choose to treat a module as a unit.  If class A is part of the public interface for the module and classes B+C aren’t, then there’d be no reason for you necessarily to have tests that specifically target classes B+C, since the accessible functionality would be being tested through the other classes that form the public interface.

The main problem with your first approach is its scalability.  I’ll demonstrate with some very simple code (it's in C#, but I'm sure you can translate).

```
public class C {
    public int Method3(int cParam) {
        if (cParam > 0) {
            return cParam + 1;
        }
        else {
            return cParam - 1;
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    C _cInstance = new C();
    public int Method2(int bParam, int cParam) {
        if (bParam > 0) {
            return bParam + 1 * _cInstance.Method3(cParam);
        }
        else {
            return bParam - 1 * _cInstance.Method3(cParam);
        }
    }
}

public class A {
    B _bInstance = new B();
    public int Method1(int aParam, int bParam, int cParam) {
        if (aParam > 0) {
            return aParam + 1 * _bInstance.Method2(bParam, cParam);
        }
        else {
            return aParam - 1 * _bInstance.Method2(bParam, cParam);
        }
    }
}
```

To test all branches using class based unit testing, at minimum you’ve got 2 branches to test in each class, so you’ve got 2+2+2=6 test cases.  If you’re going with approach 1, exhaustive testing of all classes, through class A, then instead of adding up the branches from each operation you need to multiply it, so instead you’d have 2*2*2=8.  Not a lot of difference in this case, but if you did additional validation, such as MAX/MIN int values for parameters and 0, you'd be testing 5 scenarios for each value which gives you closer to 15 vs 125 scenarios.  The more branches/values you have to test through your high level, the faster your testing scenarios multiply.  Now consider the situation if the operation in class C is slow (say 1 second).  With option 2, this impacts 2 tests, with option 1, this impacts ALL 8 of the tests, the tests are starting to become painful.  What happens if some requirement changes and class D is created?  It also uses class B and subsequently class C.  With option 1, you need to retarget all of the different values again for using class B+C.  You’re essentially writing tests again for the same thing.  Testing with option 1 is really starting to hurt now, running the tests is painfully slow and that’s without even considering hitting any outside systems.  With option 2, you Mock out B and test only the functionality of D.

In my experience if you go down route 1 then you are likely to create too many, unnecessary tests that make your test suite slow and/or you’re going to start missing scenarios.

I’m going to rewrite option 2 as

> Write unit tests that test each class or component exhaustively. Write
>   appropriate end-to-end tests to validate data flows through the system
>   as expected.  Don't try to exhaustively test all possible inputs.

As I’ve said, it may be that for your particular scenario it’s appropriate to treat classes A, B and C as a single unit/component.  But if it isn’t, then testing the individual classes in isolation helps to control the number of scenarios that need to be tested and hence the amount of effort required to test thoroughly.  It also helps to reduce the problem domain that the individual writing the tests needs to hold in their head.  It’s a lot easier to look at the branches in the class under test than try to remember all of the possible branches in all of the code that the class you’re testing calls.

The reason I’ve modified option 2 is that having unit-testing as your primary concern doesn’t mean that you automatically reduce end-to-end testing to a second class citizen, but they do have different jobs.  If you were writing to a database for example, you might have unit tests to validate that you don’t try to write strings longer than a certain value, and then have an integration test to validate that you can write strings that are that long.  The two work together, not in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, forsvarir. I covered the combinatorial explosion part by saying, "Write unit tests only when needed, like if a particular class is not adequately tested by the end-to-end test". In other words, we're not going to write thousands of tests, but we'll just make an ATTEMPT to test as many possible inputs/outputs/internal states via end-to-end tests, and then write unit tests for the remaining cases. With that qualification, would you agree with option 1 in my question?

Comment: To address your other point, you can consider A, B and C to be classes or components. In Java, all components are modeled as classes, but that's a detail that doesn't affect this question. Let's just think of A, B and C as some units that need to be tested.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi I've eddited a response into my answer, but the short answer is no, I personally still prefer option 2.

Comment: I'm afraid you're still interpreting my points in an absolute sense. Option 1 does not say that you should end-to-end tests at all costs, just that you'd write them in preference to unit tests. If that results in a combinatorial explosion, then you write unit tests. If you have a class with substantial functionality that's not already tested adequately by end-to-end tests, then you write a unit test. So, when you add a new class D or E, you write a test that tests this class and its dependencies (without mocking them out) if possible, or a unit test otherwise (by mocking out dependencies).

Comment: Running all tests shouldn't be a problem. I'm not talking about hour-long tests here, but a few seconds or minutes. If you have an hour-long test, then, yes, I agree it would be beneficial to add a smaller test that runs quicker.

Comment: Correcting typo: Option 1 does not say that you should [WRITE] end-to-end tests at all costs, just that you'd write them in preference to unit tests.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi Putting aside time to run, I think you could manage this approach on a small project. For a larger project, I don’t think you’re addressing the complexity issues of your approach at all. When you are adding class D,E,F,G that depends on B, how do you know what elements of B are already tested/need to be tested. If C is removed from the system, then what? If adding class D only results in the addition of a single test as you've suggested, how is this different to option 2? I don’t believe the complexity of what’s tested where for option 1 scales to a system with 100s of classes.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to say that I'll start with testing all behaviors of the top-level classes in the system, without mocking out their dependencies (that's how it's different from option 2, which, being a unit test, mocks out the dependencies of each class). So, if I add a new top-level class, or add new functionality in an existing top-level class, I'll try to write an end-to-end test for that. It's obvious what functionality is already being tested via end-to-end tests, because I can see the tests and how they map to the functionality of the class.

Comment: For example, if our overall server's job is to convert a spreadsheet to PDF format, and if we have a low-level class that decides where page breaks must occur, then an end-to-end test can test that a certain spreadsheet when converted to PDF has N pages, with the expected text on each page. That amounts to testing the page break detector indirectly, via end-to-end tests. Now, if there's some logic or state or behavior in the page break detector that can't be tested this way, THEN and ONLY THEN will I write a unit test for the page break detector. Is my approach clear now?

Comment: @KartickVaddadi I believe I understand your approach, I just don't agree with it.  I've posted an alternate answer that gives a concrete example of some code + tests that I would write, along with the impact that scenarios would have on those tests.  Feel free to downvote if it's not useful / correct my assumptions if they're wrong.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi I've removed my second answer, since I don't think it really adds any value given what you've said.  I'm happy to accept we have different views.  For large projects I've worked on I don't believe option 1 would work sustainably.  For others it might, but ultimately what works for you and your team is the way to go.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again for your help. BTW, I did upvote this answer because I think it was useful (it made some good points), though we have different views.